# How to convert datatype from int to datetime for year column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data with column called year only and data type is `int` I wanted to change to `datetime` data type. I have used many method but I can't get what I wanted.

Here is my data:

[image]

How can I change **Year** column to datetime object type? There are no months and dates in this column.

Answer (score 1):

`to_datetime()` with a format

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"year":pd.RangeIndex(1970,1980)})
df.year = pd.to_datetime(df["year"], format="%Y")
df
```

### output

```
    year
0   1970-01-01
1   1971-01-01
2   1972-01-01
3   1973-01-01
4   1974-01-01
5   1975-01-01
6   1976-01-01
7   1977-01-01
8   1978-01-01
9   1979-01-01
```

Comment: The output should be

Year

1970
1971
1972
1973
1974
etc

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that converting each year to the 1st of January is fine:

```py
df['year_datetime'] = df.year.map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(f'{x}-01-01'))
```

Comment: Only **Year** should be printed without month or dates. 1970, 1971, 1972, so forth